# How to do Many-to-Many / Junction Table Implementation in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to do a many to many relation in Spring JPA.

For ease of understanding I would use the Employee-Project example from here. I have a similar problem.
Lets take example from here
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

Over here I have an Employees Table & a Project Table.
I have models defined for them which I can fetch individually without working with the other.

Now I have a Junction Table which contains the relationship. Both table have other relationships with other kind of tables as well.

I have a Employee Table

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class) })
public class Employee implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class) })
public class Project implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String project_name;
```

Now I want to get all employees by a project. For that I created a Junction Table Model.
In the example I mentioned above both refered to each other in their own model. I do not want to do that as it would create tight coupling and the Models would be refering to other tables as well. So we need a junction table for that.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "relationship_employee_project")
@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class) })
public class RelationshipViewPerson implements Serializable {


  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
  private Employee employee;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", nullable = false)
  private Project project;

  public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
  }

  public void setProject(Project project) {
    this.project = project;
  }

}
```

Now when I try to build the project the instantiation of bean is failing.

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.company.domain.project.model.RelationshipEmployeeProject
```

The object should not have an Id of its own. The object would just be 2 column table in SQL with employee_id and project_id

How should I tackle this issue? I am fairly new to Spring, so do not know the nooks and crooks of it.

Comment: What don't you understand in the error message: `No identifier specified for entity: com.company.domain.project.model.RelationshipEmployeeProject` ? Your entity have to have an `Id`.

Comment: Please refer (also) to https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many ! ..Chapter 3 shows the case, where you need/want additional attributes with your "junction table"..;)

Comment: In addition to @xerx593's comment, you can also check [Vlad Mihalcea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025118/vlad-mihalcea)'s [blog article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/) on how to map many-to-many with junction table. As Hibernate is pointing out to you, you're missing primary key for your junction entity. As you would have `(employee_id, project_id)` as primary key for the junction table, you also need to specify the same for the entity.